# SQL get single row based on multiple condition after group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

Need help with creating query for below case :

Suppose I have a Table with following records

```
Name      Date        Time   Category CategoryKey
John      10/20/2012  10:00  Low       2
Sam       10/20/2012  10:00  High      4
Harry     10/20/2012  10:00  Medium    1
Michael   10/20/2012  10:00  Grey      3
Rob       10/22/2013  11:00  Low       2
Marry     10/23/2014  12:00  Low       2
Richard   10/23/2014  12:00  Grey      3
Jack      10/24/2015  1:30   High      4
```

Then If there are multiple Names for same date and time then force select only one record based on following logic and stop when any 1 of the following condition is met.

```
If Category is Medium then take name 
Else If Category is High then take name
Else If Category is Low then take name
Else If Category is Grey then take name
```

So that the Final result will be

```
Name      Date        Time   Category CategoryKey

Harry     10/20/2012  10:00  Medium    1
Rob       10/22/2013  11:00  Low       2
Marry     10/23/2014  12:00  Low       2
Jack      10/24/2015  1:30   High      4
```

Comment: Odd, all rows for a date have the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method is `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by date, time
                                order by (case category when 'Medium' then 1 when 'High' then 2 when 'Low' then 3 when 'Grey' then 4 else 5 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

It can be convenient to use string functions here:

```
             row_number() over (partition by date, time
                                order by charindex(category, 'Medium,High,Low,Grey')
                               ) as seqnum
```

This works for your case, but you need to be a little careful that all values are included and that none "contain" another value.